# Mongoose Populate Empty Array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema    
const logEntry = new Schema({
    no:{
        type: Number
    },
    type: {
        type: String
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.new  
    },
    ingredients: {
        type: String
    },
    process: {
        type: String
    },
    cook: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'shef'
    }]
});

const shefEntry = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    dish: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'logDetails'
    }
})

const foodItem = mongoose.model('logDetails', logEntry);
const Cook = mongoose.model('shef', shefEntry);
```

This is my Schema.

```
app.route('/log_entries')
    .get(controller.index)
    .post(controller.create)
```

This is my route.

```
    exports.index = function(req, res){
    logEntry.find({})
    .populate('Cook')
    .exec(function(err, logEntry){
        if(err) res.send(err);
            res.json(logEntry);
    })
}
```

This is my controller where I'm trying to populate. My requirement is to populate the name of cook into recipe collection but I get the result as

```
{
    "cook": [],
    "_id": "5dafdbd8b9cefa2670ab73c7",
    "no": 101,
    "type": "Non-Veg",
    "ingredients": "Gobi,Paneer",
    "process": "Go on with the manual",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "cook": [],
    "_id": "5dbb76bf5356143124d3afbd",
    "no": 101,
    "type": "veg",
    "ingredients": "Gobi,Paneer",
    "process": "Go on with the manual",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Can anyone explain how to use mongoose populate? I mean about how to join 2 collections and which collection to make main collection. Also refer me with some good website where I can learn more about mongoose join.

Answer (score 0):

**Cook** replace with **cook**

```
  exports.index = function(req, res){
        logEntry.find({})
        .populate('cook')
        .exec(function(err, logEntry){
            if(err) res.send(err);
                res.json(logEntry);
        }) }
```